# I need help, Im trying to count the amount of elements in a list?

Tags: prolog

Help I am trying to write a function in Prolog that will show the number of calls a person made i try some ways but came up short in the process it didn't work.
Here are facts:

```
customer('Johnsten',
     [['Arizona',1],
      ['Arkansas',1],
      ['California',1],
      ['Georgia',1],
      ['Idaho',1],
      ['Kentucky',1],
      ['Mississippi',1],
      ['New York',1],['Ohio',1],
      ['Utah',1],
      ['Canada',1],
     ['Local',1]
     ]).
customer('Jones',
     [['Local', 12],
      ['Canada',6],
     ['Local', 5],['Ohio', 8],]).
```

this is how I tried implementing it:

```
calls(X):-
   Y is calls(X,[_,_]),
   write(X),
   write(' made '),
   write(Y),
   write('calls')nl.
```

its supposed to be calls(X)
output "X made Y calls."

Comment: calls(X,[_,_]) refers to a function calls which takes two arguments; but you don't have such a function.  Also, Y is <something> requires that <something> be an arithmetic calculation.  Can you tell me what correct output would be?  For example, did Johnsten make 12 calls, or 12+6+5+8=31?

Comment: `calls(X):-calls(X,Cs),aggregate(sum(C),S^member([S,C],Cs),Tot),...`

Comment: Johnson made 12 calls